# How to validate a form for following scenario?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm relatively new to web development. I'm using HTML, jQuery and PHP for my website. I want to design a form and validate it in a following way:

- A simple webpage which has input boxes - 2 in a row and 10 rows. i.e. key = value  | One input box for 'key' & one for 'value'
- Below this form, there should be a 'Submit' button
- The action for Submit button should be that a url should be generated like www.abc.com/samplephp?key1=value1&key2=value2&……&key10=value10
- Key=Value should be only appended if not null
- When the url is formed and submitted, the php script should handle all the incoming GET parameters and save them in DB in a table

Can anyone help me in creating the form in this manner and validating it as per the given requirement using jQuery? The main issue I'm facing is in naming the text field names and accessing them in jQuery. I got totally messed up with this task. Please help me to satisfy the above four conditions. I'll do the fifth requirement on my self. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Thanks for helping me in writing jQuery code. But can you help me in desigining the form as per the requirement? I'm not getting how to name the textfields and create a form. Can you help in this regard please? Thank you all once again and waiting for your replies on HTML design of the form.

Comment: **Off Topic**:  _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like,

**PHP**

```
<?php
   $querystring=explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
   $newData=array();
   foreach($querystring as $keyPair)
   {
       $kparr=explode('=',$keyPair);
       $key=trim($kparr[0]);
       $value=trim($kparr[1]);
       if($key and $value)
       {
          $newData[$key]=$value;
       }
   }
   print_r($newData);// your final array having valid key values
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="GET" onsubmit="return false">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="key[]" value="key1" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="value[]" value="value1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="key[]" value="key2" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="value[]" value="value2" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="key[]" value="key3" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="value[]" value="value2" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').on('click',function(){
        var qs=[];
        $('input[name="key[]"]').each(function(index){
            k=$(this).val();
            v=$('input[name="value[]"]:eq('+index+')').val();
            if(k && v){// only for non-empty key value pair
                qs.push(k+'='+v);
            }
        });
        alert(qs.join('&'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/PdkSd/1

Comment: Should really check client-side too or you could end up with an invalid query string.

Comment: Thanks for helping me in writing jQuery code. But can you help me in desigining the form as per the requirement? I'm not getting how to name the textfields and create a form. Can you help in this regard please? Thank you all once again and waiting for your replies on HTML design of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var Keyvalues = ""; 

$("input[type=text]").each(function(){ if($.trim($(this).val()) != ""){
Keyvalues = Keyvalues + $(this).attr("id") + "=" + $(this).val() + "&";
}
 });
Keyvalues = Keyvalues.substring(0, Keyvalues.length - 1); 

alert(Keyvalues);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me in writing jQuery code. But can you help me in desigining the form as per the requirement? I'm not getting how to name the textfields and create a form. Can you help in this regard please? Thank you all once again and waiting for your replies on HTML design of the form.