# How to create(HTML design) and validate a form using jQuery for following scenario?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm a newbie in web development. I'm using HTML, jQuery and PHP for my website. First of all I want to design a form and validate it using jQuery in a following manner and later on generate an URL and use it as an action of form:

- A simple webpage which has input boxes - 2 in a row and 10 rows. i.e. key = value  | One input box for 'key' & one for 'value'
- Below this form, there should be a 'Submit' button
- The action for Submit button should be that a url should be generated like www.abc.com/samplephp?key1=value1&key2=value2&……&key10=value10
- Key=Value should be only appended if not null
- When the url is formed and submitted, the php script should handle all the incoming GET parameters and save them in DB in a table

Can anyone help me in creating the form in this manner and validating it as per the given requirement using jQuery? The main issue I'm facing is in naming the text field names and accessing them in jQuery. I got totally messed up with this task. Plese help me to satisfy the above four conditions. I'll do the fifth requirement on my self. Note that after validating the form completely the said URL should be formulated as per given in the requirement and it should act as an action for the form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've already asked this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763092/how-to-validate-a-form-for-following-scenario

Comment: Please do not post [the same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763641/how-to-createhtml-design-and-validate-a-form-using-jquery-for-following-scenar).  It clutters this site and it's very unfair to those only trying to help.

Comment: Also **Off Topic**:  _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"_

Answer (score 1):

Define an attribute on all the textboxes like below

```
 <input id="key1" type="text" ctrltype="keyval">
 <input id="key2" type="text" ctrltype="keyval">
  .
  .
 <input id="key10" type="text" ctrltype="keyval">
 <input id="Value1" type="text" ctrltype="keyval">
 <input id="Value2" type="text" ctrltype="keyval">
 .
 .
 <input id="Value10" type="text" ctrltype="keyval">
```

after define a function to check the textboxes empty or not like below

```
$("input[ctrltype$='keyval']").focusout() {
 //Do as per your requirement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="key1" type="text" placeholder="key1">
```

To access an element in Jquery using it's id you would use `$('#key1').` followed by the paticualar jquery function. Though I would not really validate client side as this is a security whole. Do the valiadation when you submit the form.

Answer (score -1):

There is a jQuery plugin ta validate your forms :)

It's [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). It's very easy to implement !

But don't forget to check your received datas in your PHP files, because client can disable JS...